# Android Studio sync sdk gradle

Tags: android, file, synchronization

Android Studio files made by my ex MacBook: I can't open them on Windows. What is the problem?

[image: error message]

Comment: The path to your **SDK** is different in your PCs. Make sure to set the path to your SDK correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When you open Android Studio, at right bottom corner click on **Configure** -> **SDK Manager**, and set path.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was solved once I clicked OK. (The path has been fixed automatically) If there's still error, try to change the path to SDK manually in SDK Preferences.